# Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite sets. Then $X \times Y$ is finite and $|X \times Y| = |X| \times |Y|$.

Tags: analysis

$X$ is finite with cardinality $n$ and $Y$ is finite with cardinality $m$. Lets now assume that $|X \times Y| > |X| \times |Y| = nm$, then there music exist a subset of $Z \subset |X \times Y|$ with $|Z| = n(m+1)$.

From the above assumption we can say that there exists a bijection $h$,
$h:Z \rightarrow \mathbb{N_n} \times \mathbb{N_{m+1}}$.

So $\forall z \in \mathbb{N_n} \times \mathbb{N_{m+1}} \exists! x \in Z \text{ s.t } h(x) = z$

In particular, $\exists x \in Z \text{ s.t } h(x) = (n,m+1)$
where $x = (a,b)$.

$$\implies (a,b) = h^{-1}(n,m+1)$$

*Can I invoke the pigeonhole Principle here?*

We observe that the image of $(a,b)$ under $h$ is $(n,m+1)$.

I am unsure on how to proceed.

Comment: Why would the set $Z$ need to exist? Why $n(m+1)$ and not $nm+1$?

Comment: a direct proof with induction is much easier